# JSON with nested arrays without square brackets in PHP

Tags: php, json, brackets

There are many questions at StackOverflow that come near my question, but none answers it completely.

In order to test a POST request in an Android app, I found an example, that uses the following test API:

https://reqres.in/api/users/2

This API returns

```
{"data":{"id":2,"email":"janet.weaver@reqres.in","first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"some url"}}
```

(note: I changed the url to an image to "some url", in case this should collide with rules on StackOverflow).

My question is:
How to I make PHP to give me exact the same output?

Normally, I use something like this:

```
$result=array();
$result[]['id']=2/1; //0
$result[]['email']="janet.weaver@reqres.in"; //1
$result[]['first_name']="Janet"; //2
$result[]['last_name']="Weaver"; //3
$result[]['avatar']="some url"; //4
$data["result"]=$result;
echo json_encode($data);
```

But that puts some square brackets in the output. So: How do I imitate the output from the URL in my own PHP script?

Hope to get some input from more experienced people!

Albert

Comment: Copy paste that JSON string above into a variable, do a `json_decode`. There you go, you'll see the array structure to build.

Comment: Tried that. $str='{"data":{"id":2,"email":"janet.weaver@reqres.in","first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"some url"}}';
echo json_decode($str);

Nothing is displayed.

Comment: You can't echo an array, more like a `var_dump()` is needed.

Answer (score 3):

You're building a nested array with `$result[]['id']=2/1;`. Each of this calls adds a new associative array with a single element to the `$result` list array.

PHP encodes two things into JSON objects - associative arrays and objects. Using arrays is shorter but using objects can help to understand it better. So first an example with `stdClass`:

```
$json = new stdClass();
$json->data = $data = new stdClass();
$data->id = 2;
$data->email = "janet.weaver@reqres.in";
$data->first_name = "Janet";
$data->last_name = "Weaver";
$data->avatar= "some url";

echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Objects are references in PHP. So you a change will affect all variables with the reference. This is not the case with an array. But it can be done in just a single expression:

```
$json = [
    'data' => [
        'id' => 2/1,
        'email' => "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
        'first_name' => "Janet",
        'last_name' => "Weaver", 
        'avatar' => "some url"
    ]
];

echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example helps you, the below example has all the combinations you are expecting.

```
<?php
     $name = "Your Name";
        $yearsofexp = "Years";
        $designation = "Your designnation";


        $pro_summary->name = $name;
        $pro_summary->yearsofexp = $yearsofexp;
        $pro_summary->designation = $designation;

        $topics->tech1 = "Android";
        $topics->tech2 = "Java";
        $topics->tech3 ="PHP";

        $past_exp[]=array("comp"=> "company One", "role"=> "techlead","dates"=>"2015-2019", "main_resp"=>"coding,testing,debugging","logo"=>"some.png");
        $past_exp[]=array("comp"=> "company 2", "role"=> "senior software engineer","dates"=>"2014-2015", "main_resp"=>"coding,testing,debugging","logo"=>"some2.png");
        $past_exp[]=array("comp"=> "company 3", "role"=> "senior software developer","dates"=>"2013-2014", "main_resp"=>"coding,testing,debugging","logo"=>"some3.png");
        $past_exp[]=array("comp"=> "company 4", "role"=> "software developer","dates"=>"2010-2013", "main_resp"=>"coding,testing,debugging","logo"=>"some4.png");

        //$past_exp[] = array("px1" =>$past_exp[1],"px2" =>$past_exp[2],"px3" =>$past_exp[3],"px4" => $past_exp[4] );

        $uni[] = array("education"=>"Degree 1", "university"=>"University 1", "logo" =>"uni1.png");
        $uni[] = array("education"=>"Degree 2", "university"=>"University 2", "logo"=>"uni2.png");



        $my_cv->Professional = $pro_summary;
        $my_cv->Technology = $topics;
        $my_cv->PastExperience = $past_exp;
        $my_cv->Education = $uni;




        echo json_encode($my_cv);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jacks. I haven't tried if this works, but the answer from ThW worked.

Comment: Great to know that, try this method when u have suitable requirement.